# Elegant proof of combinatorial statement: at least $l-k+1$ children who were in larger teams

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $n$ children, who play a game where in round $1$ they spilt up in $k$ teams (every team non-empty, pairwise disjoint). After a while it gets boring, so they form new teams to play round $2$; this time, they split up in $l$ teams (every team non-empty, pairwise disjoint), where $l>k$, and this beeing the only condition.

Prove that there are at least $l-k+1$ children, for which their team in the first round was of strictly larger size than in the second round.

This was a homework problem in a course last year which I had a very hard time proving, and finally, a day before the deadline, I found a proof which was three pages long and used a pretty messy induction with a whole lot of definitions and notations I had to introduce (it took me the whole day to write).

Is there an elegant proof of this statement?

If you want to see my proof, comment below and I will try to summarize it. But I guarantee you, its very messy! :)

Answer (score 12):

Say a child in a team of size $m$ takes up $1/m$ of a team. Say child $i$ takes up $x_i$ of a team in round $1$ and $y_i$ of a team in round $2$. Now we need to show there are at least $l-k+1$ values of $i$ for which $y_i>x_i$.

But $\sum_ix_i=k$ and $\sum_iy_i=l$, so $\sum_i(y_i-x_i)=l-k$. Each term in this sum is strictly less than $1$, so there must be strictly more than $l-k$ positive terms.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the stunningly short answer, that's exactly what I was looking for. +1

Comment: May I ask how you came up with the idea? Once seen its very simple, but it is very creative; was this just a spontaneous idea, or was it motivated by a specific heuristic?

Comment: @RedundantAunt Thanks! I'm afraid I can't remember quite what I was thinking as I originally came up with this to solve a similar question some time ago, and just remembered it this time :) I think the idea was trying to use the fact that there were more teams to go around in the second round, but the same number of people, so thinking about dividing teams between people rather than people between teams made sense.

Answer (score 3):

Let there be $n$ children. Supposed there is at least 1 child that is in a small or equal size group in round 1 than in round 2. Let's examine what happens with this child removed.

Case 1: The removed child's round 1 and round 2 group remains non-empty. This results in $n-1$ children but does not change $k$ or $l$.

Case 2: The removed child's round 1 becomes empty. This results in $n-1$ children, $k-1$ groups in round 1 and $l$ groups in round 2. Then the question is to prove that there are at least $l - (k-1) + 1 > l - k + 1$ children for which their team in the first round was of strictly larger size than in the second round.

Case 3: The removed child's round 1 and round 2 become empty. This results in $n$, $k$, $l$ all reduced by 1 and does not change the question.

Case 4: The removed child's round 2 becomes empty. This is impossible, since that means the round 2 group has a smaller size.

With the above 4 cases, we can conclude that if we remove all the children that is in a smaller or equal size group in round 1 than in round 2 and ends up with $n'$ children, $k'$ groups in round 1 and $l'$ groups in round 2, the resulting quantity $l' - k' + 1 \ge l - k + 1$.

All there's left to do is to look at $n'$ children with all children in round 1 being in a larger group than in round 2. Let these children be in groups $K_1,...,K_{k'}$ in round 1 and $L_1,...,L_{l'}$ in round 2 (non-empty, pairwise disjoint). There are clearly at least $l' \ge l' - k' + 1 \ge l-k+1$ children.